# Can't get property 'dayOfTheMonth' of java.lang.String

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, jodatime

Im using Grails and createCriteria to narrow down search results based on a whether a date is between 2 user input dates. The problem I'm having occurs when all the date properties that are being searched happen to be null. This causes an error saying

> can't get property dayOfTheMonth of a java.lang.String

Is there a way around this? If I change the Database to give one of the user a date it works, this only occurs when all are null.

```
    def c = User.createCriteria()
    DateTime tempDobStart = new DateTime(Integer.parseInt(params.dobStart_year), Integer.parseInt(params.dobStart_month), Integer.parseInt(params.dobStart_day), 0, 0)
    DateTime tempDobEnd = new DateTime(Integer.parseInt(params.dobEnd_year), Integer.parseInt(params.dobEnd_month), Integer.parseInt(params.dobEnd_day), 0, 0)
    def results = c.list(params) {
        and {
            if (username) {
                ilike("username", '%' + username.trim() + '%')
            }

            if (firstName) {
                ilike("firstName", '%' + firstName.trim() + '%')
            }

            if (lastName) {
                ilike("lastName", '%' + lastName.trim() + '%')
            }
            if (tempDobStart && tempDobEnd) {
                between("dob", tempDobStart, tempDobEnd)
            }
        }
    return results
```

Comment: I think this is more of a question of how your business logic should validate against null values. I would suggest to validate params before calling Integer.parseInt or have default dobStart/End values.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question at all, but please...just "Grails". There is no such thing as Groovy on Grails. See Burt Beckwith's blog post: https://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1213

Comment: Haave you tried to add a criterion `isNotNull("dob")` in addition to the `between(...)` criterion to avoid comparing null values with dates?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being a completely different problem, when i was redirecting back to the search page, it was attempting to repopulated what i had attempted to search even thought it wasnt in the correct format.